# Shortest code special string sort

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Objective/Restrictions:

1. May only be answered with programming language that has function syntax (or procedure, method, lambda, macro, statement grouping and labelling) .
2. Create a function with at least 2 argument/parameter, that generates an array containing 7 random strings, each string contains 3 characters, string may only contain alphanumeric characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. The number 7 and 3 passed into the function
3. Create a function that sort those strings using in special alphabetical ascending order: number first, alphabet later (lower-case then upper-case), for example:

   ```
   1aa
   2ac
   aab
   abc
   Aab
   bAA
   BZ2
   ```
4. Create a function to print each string in descending order from the last one to the first one without mutating the ascending ordered array.
5. Call all three function and produce the correct output
6. Shortest code wins!

**Note**: if possible, give the [ideone](http://ideone.com/FYVgb4) (this one also example implementation in Ruby) or any other online compiler link to test the correctness.

Comment: care to explain why `-1`, and now `-2`?

Comment: All the restrictions and requirements seem arbitrary and thrown together. Because you're saying what each step needs to do, there's little room for cleverness. Your challenge looks decent and well-specified, but I wouldn't want to work on it. I'd prefer a task that just told me what task my code needed to achieve, meaning the connection the output must have to the input, and let me figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: people here are quite mean to me.. XD `-5` now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## J - 70 chars

```
a=:'0123456789',6}.26|.a.{~65+i.58
b=:{&a@?@$&62
c=:/:62&#.@(a&i.)
d=:\:~
```

Usage: `d c b 7 3`

Comment: I was looking for ways to shorten your `a`, but I only found `a.#~(0j48 10j7 26j6 26j133)#4$1`, which has the same length.

Comment: @FUZxxl `'0123456789'` is `(1":i.10)`, that's -3 chars

Comment: @FUZxxl `48}.a.#~(58j7 26j6 26j133)#3$1` saves 1 char on your idea

Comment: `b=:a{~?@$&62`, `c=:/:a&i.`, and `d=:|.` are shorter. Further, this definition of `a` gives a flat-out wrong solution, because it sorts incorrectly. Try `a=:(1":i.10),,97,.&(26$}.&a.)65`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 - 181 chars

Ungolfed

```
@z=(0..9,a..z,A..Z);

sub d{
    map{ tr/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/; $_ } @_
}

# n - number of strings to generate
# l - length of strings
sub a{
    ($n,$l) = @_;
    $a .= $z[rand@z] for 1..$n*$l;
    ($a=~/(.{$l})/g)
}

sub b{
    d(sort d(@_))
}

sub c{
    for(-$#_..0){
        print "$_[-$_]\n"
    }
}

c b a 7,3
```

Golfed

```
@z=(0..9,a..z,A..Z);sub d{map{tr/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/;$_}@_}sub a{($n,$l)=@_;$a.=$z[rand@z]for 1..$n*$l;($a=~/(.{$l})/g)}sub b{d(sort d(@_))}sub c{for(-$#_..0){print"$_[-$_]\n"}}c b a 7,3
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl6   145 chars

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

my@a='a'..'z';
my@b='A'..'Z';
my@c=^10,@a,@b;

# first argument $^a is the number of strings
# second argument $^b is the length of the strings
sub a{@c.roll($^b).join xx$^a};

# sub b{@_.sort} # numbers then upper then lower
sub b{@_.sort(*.trans(@a,@b Z=>@b,@a))}; # swaps upper and lower

sub c{say @_.reverse};

c b a 7,3
```

```perl6
my@a='a'..'z';my@b='A'..'Z';my@c=^10,@a,@b;sub a{@c.roll($^b).join xx$^a};sub b{@_.sort(*.trans(@a,@b Z=>@b,@a))};sub c{say @_.reverse};c b a 7,3
```

After removing the comments and all of the newlines, I get 145 characters.

If the requirements were changed so that the strings were sorted by numbers then uppercase then lowercase, I could remove 25 characters from the `b` subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 141

Fairly straightforward solution. Uses recursion to generate the random `String`s and makes use of `String#tr` to make the sorting short and sweet.

```ruby
O=[*?0..?9]+[*?A..?Z]+[*?a..?z] 
r=->i,s{i<1?[]:([O.sample(s)*'']+r[i-1,s])}
s=->a{a.sort_by{|e|e.tr"A-Za-z","a-zA-Z"}}
p=->a{puts a.reverse}
```

Usage: `p[s[r[7,3]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 339 chars

```
X=[*('0'..'9')]+[*('a'..'z')].map{|c|[c,c.upcase]}.flatten
Y={};v=0;X.each{|c|Y[c]=(v+=1)}
def x n;n.times.to_a.map{X[(rand()*X.length).to_i]}.join '';end
def y m,n;m.times.to_a.map{x n};end
def z r;r.sort{|a,b|v=-1;w=0;a.each_char{|c|d=b[v+=1];next if c==d;w=(Y[c]<Y[d]?-1:1);break};w};end
def a b;b.reverse_each{|c|puts c};end
a z(y 7,3)
```

verify [here](http://ideone.com/FYVgb4)